# Oracle text search on multiple tables and joins

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, lexer, oracle-text

I have the following SQL statement.

```
select emp_no,dob,dept_no from v_depts
where catsearch (emp_no,'abc',NULL) > 0
or
catsearch (dept_no,'abc',NULL) > 0
```

where `v_depts` is a view.

Now I would like to add one or more tables as join so that I can do text search on columns
e.g. `employee_details` contains employee information and I can join with `emp_no`

I have created index on `employee_details` table for `emp_name` column, however I am not able to join with v_depts to search because I modify my sql statement as

```
select a.emp_no,a.dob,a.dept_no from v_depts a left outer join employee_details b
on (a.emp_no = b.emp_no)
where catsearch (a.emp_no,'abc',NULL) > 0
or
catsearch (a.dept_no,'abc',NULL) > 0
or
catsearch (b.emp_name,'abc',NULL) > 0
```

it gives me error

```
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10849: catsearch does not support functional invocation
DRG-10599: column is not indexed
```

even though I have created index for emp_name column in `employee_details` table. How can I solve this problem?

Index statement for emp_name

```
CREATE INDEX IDX_EMP_DETAILS ON EMPLOYEE_DETAILS(EMP_NAME)INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CTXCAT
```

Comment: How come you do not get `column ambiguously defined` error? You have no table alias prefix before `emp_no` in your query in the `SELECT` list and when passing `emp_no` as a parameter to `catsearch`. Are you sure the error you get is caused by the `catsearch (b.emp_name,'abc',NULL) > 0`? If you remove that line, does it work?

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej I have modified question and added alias name, it was missed while typing question. If I remove `catsearch (b.emp_name,'abc',NULL) > 0`, then it does return results correctly.

Comment: Could you add the `CREATE INDEX` statement that you issued to create the index for `emp_name` column?

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej I have added index statement for `emp_name` in my question.

Comment: Could you try adding a hint like this: `select /*+ INDEX(employee_details IDX_EMP_DETAILS) */ a.emp_no,a.dob,a.dept_no from` ... (the rest of your query).

Comment: @PrzemyslawKruglej I do have `/*+ INDEX(employee_details IDX_EMP_DETAILS) */` however it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39593/discussion-between-przemyslaw-kruglej-and-polppan)

Comment: It's actually the OR that causes this; if you changed it to a AND it would work. [Tom Kyte has done something on multi-table context indexes](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5533095920114) but it does seem overly complicated considering that it works with a AND... The actual error is because it's not using the text index but is trying to use CATSEARCH.

Comment: @Ben Idea is to use OR not AND, so that it will look for a text in any of the columns.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you don't want to use OR, it's just the reason for the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually solve fulltext searches on multiple columns on different tables by materializing a structured XML view of them and then creating the index on the whole XML.

This solution is generic and also give you freedom on search: the whole view or only a subpath. The drawback is managing the refresh of a MV who usually cannot be refreshed fast; but update of fulltext index usually isn't in real-time, too, so you can just schedulate it.

```
-- Crating the view
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW fulltext_helper
NOLOGGING
BUILD DEFERRED
REFRESH COMPLETE ON DEMAND
AS
SELECT 
   a.dob, -- we don't need to fulltext on him
   XMLELEMENT(helper,
     XMLFOREST(a.emp_no AS emp_no, 
              a.dept_no AS dept_no, 
              b.emp_name AS emp_name)
   ) AS indexme
FROM v_depts a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN employee_details b
ON (a.emp_no = b.emp_no);

-- Creating the index
BEGIN
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('fulltext_helper_lexer', 'BASIC_LEXER');
    ctx_ddl.create_preference('fulltext_helper_filter', 'NULL_FILTER');
END;
/
CREATE INDEX fulltext_helper_index ON fulltext_helper (indexme)
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT PARAMETERS (
    'DATASTORE CTXSYS.DIRECT_DATASTORE
     LEXER fulltext_helper_lexer
     FILTER fulltext_helper_filter');

-- Searching the whole data
SELECT * FROM fulltext_helper
WHERE contains(indexme, '{abc} INPATH (/helper)') > 0;

-- Searching only on "empno"
SELECT * FROM fulltext_helper
WHERE contains(indexme, '{abc} INPATH (/helper/emp_no)') > 0;
```

Comment: How does XML view helps text search and how it differs from normal materialized view? Thanks

Comment: Another question I would like to ask is while creating MV should I add emp_no,dob,dept_no etc. as additional columns so that when I retrieve records I can select those columns? Or I should join with primary key in order to fetch those columns from tables? Which is a better option?

Comment: XML let you keep a structure on your data and selecting where to search just in string condition: in above example we have a plain one-level XML, but could be a complex tree where you need to search a whole subtree.

Comment: No need to join back to have indexed column: you will just take them from the XML by XMLTable or EXTRACTVALUE operators.

Comment: My only problem remains is refresh of MV :-)

Comment: Refreshing policy depends on size and volatility of your data: you could just refresh on commit, or schedule an hourly refresh with an "on demand" option, or creating an elaborate logic backed by some triggers and a background working scheduler job...