# Oracle text search with boolean operators

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-text

I have the following query where I am searching text in xmlpath, this is in continuation with this post [Oracle text search on multiple tables and joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476447/oracle-text-search-on-multiple-tables-and-joins)

I would like to use AND, OR boolean operators for searching, I have tried as mentioned in this document 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb09sea.htm#CBBBHJJJ

```
SELECT * FROM my_mv
WHERE contains(testindexcol, '{smith AND CATHY} INPATH (/helper)') > 0;
```

however it doesn't return any results, how can I use boolean operators like AND, OR with Oracle Text search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, you escaped the operators by enclosing them in curly brackets:

```
{smith AND CATHY}
```

Try moving them outside, i.e.,

```
{smith} AND {CATHY}
```