# Oracle Text Search on certain columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-text, oracle-xml-db

How to use Oracle Text Search `contains` on multiple fields?

I would like to search only on `emp_name` and `supervisor`,so I have used the following query

```
SELECT * FROM fulltext_helper WHERE contains(indexme,'jack and  
jill(/HELPER/EMP_NAME/SUPERVISOR)') > 0;
```

However it didn't fetch any results.

How I can use certain columns from a table or materialized view to search with and without boolean operators.

Comment: See my solution, it works also on multiple tables:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476447/oracle-text-search-on-multiple-tables-and-joins/19483275#19483275

Comment: @dbra Yes I have seen that and question posted by yours truly and thanks for your answer. Would like to know how to do on multiple columns of same table or materialized view? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the path "/HELPER/EMP_NAME/SUPERVISOR" tells him to search on leaf like "...", which doesn't exists; furthermore you shoud specify the [INPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm#i997443) operator.

The right syntax is:

```
CONTAINS(indexme,'jack INPATH(/HELPER/EMP_NAME) and jill INPATH(/HELPER/SUPERVISOR)') > 0;
```

Comment: I see `HELPER/EMP_NAME/SUPERVISOR` means it will search for sub elements right?

Comment: And by the way how search can be done for between two date fields? E.g. all `employees created_date between '01-Jan-2012' and '01-Dec-2012'`

Comment: Oracle text just searches... text! It has many way to do it, even with soundex, but doesn't understand semantic of text - numbers, dates an so on.

Anyway, you could filter your results in the WHERE clause, adding condition on date extracted (with EXCTRACT operator) from XML and converted back into number date type with TO_DATE operator.

Comment: Yes, you are right, only for keywords :-) Thanks again dbra, appreciated.

Comment: How can I use wildcard like %?

Comment: In the usual way, but you must be aware they are actually expanded in a list of all words on index that matches, and number of words admitted is limited. Usually are far more useful operators like SOUNDEX and NEAR. cfr. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm#i998461

Comment: Looks like Oracle text search is a like an ocean, so many different alternates and predicates. Thanks a lot dbra.